# Induction proof of $T(n)=T(\lfloor \alpha n \rfloor)+T(\lfloor(1−\alpha)n\rfloor)+1=O(n)$

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics, recurrence-relations, computational-complexity, recursion

Im trying to prove the following using induction but I am stuck with a constant in my induction step which I can't rid of:

$T\left(n\right)=T\left(\left\lfloor\alpha n\right\rfloor\right)+T\left(\left\lfloor(1-\alpha)n\right\rfloor\right)+1=O\left(n\right) \ \ \ \ for\ \ \ \alpha<1.$

Target: want to show for a specific constant $c>0$ and "big enough"   $ n $   that $T\left(n\right)\le c\cdot n$

***base case:***

Assuming $T(0)=1$ and showing for $n=1$:

For every constant $c\geq3 $ , the folloing it true: $T\left(1\right)=T\left(\left\lfloor\alpha\right\rfloor\right)+T\left(\left\lfloor(1-\alpha)\right\rfloor\right)+1\le1+1+1=3\le c\cdot1$

***induction step:***
$ T\left(n\right)=T\left(\left\lfloor\alpha n\right\rfloor\right)+T\left(\left\lfloor(1-\alpha)n\right\rfloor\right)+1\le\ c\cdot\left\lfloor\alpha n\right\rfloor+\ c\cdot\left\lfloor(1-\alpha)n\right\rfloor+1\le c\cdot an+\ c\cdot(1-\alpha)n+1\le cn+1$

And this is where I get stuck

I would like to say someting like $\left\lfloor a n\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor(1-\alpha)n\right\rfloor\le n-1$  , but well, it is not accurate for exampla in case $\alpha=\frac{1}{3}$ and $n=9$

Any assistance would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(n) = T(n)+1$; then the recurrence relation for $T(n)$ becomes
$$
    T(n) + 1 = T(\lfloor \alpha n\rfloor) + 1 + T(\lfloor (1-\alpha) n\rfloor) + 1
$$
after we add $1$ to both sides, and this simplifies to
$$
   f(n)  = f(\lfloor \alpha n\rfloor) + f(\lfloor(1-\alpha)n\rfloor).
$$
We can begin by proving $f(n) = O(n)$; now, the approach you're taking will work just fine, because the inequality we need is $\left\lfloor \alpha n\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor(1-\alpha)n\right\rfloor\le n$, and this is always true.

This means $T(n) = O(n)$ because $T(n) \le f(n)$.

Comment: Many thanks!
May I ask why I doesn't work directly like I did?
I have never had a case like that which I coudn't get rid of a constant and had to use another function, just being curious what is different here...

Comment: slao, shoudn it be f(n)=T(n)-1? something is still not working for me

Comment: To answer your second question first, see my edit; I've spelled out how we go from $T(n)$ to $f(n)$.

Comment: To answer your first question: this happens when the recurrence is not homogeneous (due to the $+1$ at the end). The substitution with $f(n)$ turns it into a homogeneous recurrence. A simpler example is the recurrence $a_n = 3a_{n-1} - 1$ with $a_0 = 1$, which is hard to solve. But subtract $\frac12$ and we get $a_n - \frac12 = 3(a_{n-1} - \frac12)$ so $a_n - \frac12 = 3^n (a_0 - \frac12)$, giving us a closed form quickly.

Comment: Ho cool, I would never guess that it was the problem. When you say "recurrence is not homogeneous" , does it imlies for something like this as well? T(n)=T(n/2)+n ? or only if there is an addition of a constatnt which is not zero ?

Comment: Adding $+n$ also causes problems, and also stops it from being homogeneous. In the example of $T(n) = T(n/2) + n$, we can subtract $2n$ from both sides, and get $T(n) - 2n = T(n/2) - n = T(n/2) - 2 (n/2)$. This is $f(n) = f(n/2)$ for $f(n) = T(n) - 2n$.

Comment: Got you! thank you so much!